# Color Filler Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

Is there an algorithm that fills the area outside the edges?

e.g.:

From this

[image]

to this

[image]

Comment: Yes, flood fill run from an appropriate point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming for simplicity that the edges don't touch the image boundary (you can always guarantee that by adding a pixel-wide "frame"), you can simply run flood fill from an arbitrary point on the image boundary.

Comment: And these are the moments where I would say, "Why didn't I think of that". Thank you sir.